# How to get mobile page scaling correctly?

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

Everything scales fine on desktop. Almost everything scales fine on mobile as well, except the header intro. Even the navbar scales perfectly.

Any ideas?

Added viewport width=device-width and initial sacle to the head, didn't change anything.

## Html

```
<header id="header">
  <div class="intro">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-0 intro-text">
            <h1>IRON LANDSCAPING</h1>
            <p>Bringing your home the best.</p>
            <a href="#about" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg page-scroll">More Info</a> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- About Section -->
```

## CSS

```css
.intro {
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(../img/intro-bg.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    background-color: #808080;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
```

## ScreenShot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: can you please detail what is not working or scale correctly? what you tried ? a screenshot of what is not working and what should happen instead?

Comment: my mistake! forgot to attach it.. screenshot added

Comment: Does your header-intro or its container have a width of 100% ?

Comment: yes, what should it be set to?

Comment: Please can you add the related CSS rules?

Comment: @KarlChelton done

Comment: Have you tried setting `.intro`'s `width: 100vw;` or trying `display: block;`?

Comment: @KarlChelton yes. No luck,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to lower font size of heading, it pushes other content. 
you have this in your css 
.intro h1 { font-size: 100px; } which causes your problem 
Add this line at the end of your css to make media query for screens width smaller than 800px.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 799px) {
  .intro h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
}
```

Comment: It has to work, I tested it on your website. Definitely your heading is making problems. You have to make it smaller when user has device that is less than 800px width. 
You can fix this either by making media query as I suggested in my post (remember to clear browser cache, maybe that's why you are not seing any changes), or add css property word-break: break-word; to your <h1> element

Comment: you're a genius. The browser was caching. Was definitely a late night that night! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add this to your `<Head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Read the third line in my original post.

Comment: Ok my bad :) Imma gonna check and edit my comments if i find smth :)